# Transfer space from one partition to another

Tags: partition, mount, disk-space-utilization, dedicated-server, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Linux server running Ubuntu 16.04.

I ran in to an issue this morning where one of my partitions ran out of space, I managed to free up some space as a temporary solution but need to transfer/reallocate some space from one partition to another.

Running `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  318M  2.9G  10% /run
/dev/md1         20G   19G   25M 100% /
tmpfs            16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2        201G  943M  190G   1% /home
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see `/dev/md1` is pretty much out of space, I am wanting to transfer some of the free space on `/dev/md2` to this partition as I am never going to use 201G on my `/home` directory.

How can I do this or put `/` on `/dev/md2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do this or put / on /dev/md2?
>   Reinstall but if you're going to do that then it's probably worth fixing the partitions and use LVM too.

---

This is what i would probably do. I'm going to guess that most of md1 is filled with log files, so

- Shut the system down and then bring it up in single user mode.
- Make a directory under /home for /var/log e.g. /home/varlog
- Transfer the contents of /var/log to /home/varlog
- Delete the contents of /var/log and the /var/log directory
- Link /var/log to /home/varlog

Then restart the system.

Comment: It's actually elastic search that is soaking up all the space in my `/var/lib` folder

Comment: Why don't you just tell elastic search to use a different directory then ? It would have been good for you to say that in your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I could do that - and I get now that it would've helped to mention that. Following a similar approach to what you suggested worked. In that I moved elasticsearch in to a directory inside `/home` and then told elasticsearch to use that instead - which free'd up a tonne of space. Thanks for your help!